# Deserialize JSON with multiple DefaultContractResolvers

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can (mainly) deserialize json using a custom [DefaultContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm), `StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver`. The only issue is that each property in every `Student` object in the collection `Students` is `null`.

How do I use the `StudentContractResolver` (or any other recommended method) to resolve these values correctly?

```
var json =
@"{
    'TotalCount': 854,
    'TotalPages': 9,
    'CurrentPage': 1,
    'PageSize': 100,
    'Result': [
        {
            'FName': 'Adam',
            'Mi':'A',
            'LName': 'Ant',
        },
        {
            'FName': 'Bob',
            'Mi':'B',
            'LName': 'Benson'
        }
    ]
}";

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = (StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver))
};

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentPaginatedResult>(json, settings);
```

DTOs:

```
public class StudentPaginatedResult
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Contract resolvers

```
public abstract class ContractResolverBase : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings { get; set; }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyMappings.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var resolvedName);
        return resolvedName ?? base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}

public class StudentContractResolver : ContractResolverBase
{
    public StudentContractResolver()
    {
        PropertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {nameof(Student.FirstName), "FName"},
            {nameof(Student.MiddleInitial), "Mi"},
            {nameof(Student.LastName), "LName"}
        };
    }
}

public class StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver : ContractResolverBase
{
    public StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver()
    {
        PropertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {nameof(StudentPaginatedResult.Students), "Result"}
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver` to inherit from `StudentContractResolver` instead of `ContractResolverBase`.  Then make its constructor add to the existing `PropertyMappings` dictionary rather than replacing it:

```
public class StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver : StudentContractResolver
{
    public StudentPaginatedResultContractResolver()
    {
        PropertyMappings.Add(nameof(StudentPaginatedResult.Students), "Result");
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/APSRfn